# How to bundle up chromy with browerserify to make a script to put in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

I am trying scrape to a dynamic website that loads element upon user scrolling. I am using nodejs modules chromy and browserify and cheerio.

When I run the script on my computer its works perfectly and gives me the expected results. Since I want to use this scripts on an HTML I used browserify to bundle up all the node modules including cheerio and chromy. When the page loads it gives me an error.

const cheerio = require('cheerio'); const showResult = require('./showResult'); const Chormy= require('chromy');
window.scrape= function (){
  let url= ‘https://www.newegg.com/Laptops-Notebooks/Category/ID-223?Tpk=laptops’;

newwgg(url);

function newegg(url) { 
    //const proxyUrl = 'https://secret-ocean-49799.herokuapp.com/';  
    //const result = fetch(`${url}`).then(response => response.text()); 
    let chromy= new Chormy({visible: false});

```
chromy.chain() 
.goto(url) 
.evaluate(() =>{ 
  return document.body.innerHTML; 
}) 
.result((body) => { 
  console.log(body); 
  const $= cheerio.load(body); 
  const items=$('.list-wrap').children().eq(3).children(); 
  console.log(items.length);  
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length * 2; i+= 2){ 
    const itemLink = items.children().eq(i).attr('href'); 
    var itemImage = items.children().eq(i).children().eq(1).attr('src'); 
    var itemName = items.children().eq(i).children().eq(1).attr('title'); 
    itemImage = itemImage.substring(2, itemImage.length); 
    itemName = itemName.substring(0, 60); 
    itemName = itemName.substring(0, Math.min(itemName.length, itemName.lastIndexOf(" "))); 
    //console.log(itemLink) 
    //console.log(itemImage) 
    //console.log(itemName) 
    newEggSearchResult.push(itemImage + ' | ' + itemName + ' | ' + "New" + ' | ' + '$00.00' + ' | ' + itemLink + '\n'); 
  } 
  const items2=$('.list-wrap').children().eq(7).children(); 
  console.log(items2.length); 
    for(var i = 0; i < items2.length * 2; i+= 2){ 
      const itemLink = items2.children().eq(i).attr('href'); 
      var itemImage = items2.children().eq(i).children().eq(1).attr('src'); 
      var itemName = items2.children().eq(i).children().eq(1).attr('title'); 
      itemImage = itemImage.substring(2, itemImage.length); 
      itemName = itemName.substring(0, 60); 
      itemName = itemName.substring(0, Math.min(itemName.length, itemName.lastIndexOf(" "))); 
      //console.log(itemLink) 
      //console.log(itemImage) 

      //console.log(itemName) 
      newEggSearchResult.push(itemImage + ' | ' + itemName + ' | ' + "New" + ' | ' + '$00.00' + ' | ' + itemLink + '\n'); 
    }  
    var allResult = ''; 
    for (let i = 0; i < newEggSearchResult.length; i++) { 
      allResult = allResult.concat(newEggSearchResult[i]); 
    }  
    //showResult.show(allResult, 'newegg');   
  }) 
  .end() 
  .then(() =>chromy.close());     }

}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJjyi.jpg)
[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWvgE.jpg)

Comment: The library you are using are meant for node and don't seems to work in the brower. It seems to primary be an issue with Buffer in node. Maybe you could try importing this : https://github.com/feross/buffer and assigning to the window but it's not sure at all it is going to work

Comment: This is probably not going to work. You are using a library to load a headless version of Chrome, you can't do that in a browser. Also, due to security restriction ( look up CORS), you probable won't be able to send a request to any webpage from your browser.